# Random Subgroups of Arbitrary Size

Tags: r, grouping

So I will preface this question by saying I am extremely new to R and it's taking me time to get used to the language.

So my question is this: If I have a dataset with an odd size of observations, say 983, and 12 variables, and say I wanted to place observations into 3 subgroups randomly, is there a way to do this? I have seen some other questions asked on how to do this for 2 equal subgroups, but I want to know if it's possible to do this randomly with any arbitrary sized subgroups. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sample`, if your dataframe is called `df` you can do.

```
df$group <- sample(3, nrow(df), replace = TRUE)
```

This will randomly assign 1-3 groups to each row. The probability of occurrence of each group is equal but since this is completely random it is possible that every group does not occur equal number of times always.

You can use `table(df$group)` to get a count of how many rows are present in each group.